# Radius server cannot get the client to respond to md5-challenge

Tags: c#, radius

i am Implementing the radius server with C#, use eap-md5 method for easy developing. but cannot get the client to respond, the client just keep sending access-request with different IDs after received my server response. i had verified the Authenticators are correct. is there some "Must have" attributes i am missing? thanks

here is the access request wireshark capture

```
RADIUS Protocol
Code: Access-Request (1)
Packet identifier: 0x18 (24)
Length: 159
Authenticator: 5bcaa271c9441fbc9cc9e5d622660fc1
[The response to this request is in frame 2]
Attribute Value Pairs
    AVP: l=4 t=User-Name(1): uu
    AVP: l=6 t=NAS-IP-Address(4): 192.168.0.254
    AVP: l=14 t=NAS-Identifier(32): 24a43ce687e5
    AVP: l=6 t=NAS-Port(5): 0
    AVP: l=28 t=Called-Station-Id(30): 26-A4-3C-E7-87-E5:AKRadius
    AVP: l=19 t=Calling-Station-Id(31): F0-99-BF-47-C9-4D
    AVP: l=6 t=Framed-MTU(12): 1400
    AVP: l=6 t=NAS-Port-Type(61): Wireless-802.11(19)
    AVP: l=23 t=Connect-Info(77): CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11b
    AVP: l=9 t=EAP-Message(79) Last Segment[1]
        Type: 79
        Length: 9
        EAP fragment: 028c0007017575
        Extensible Authentication Protocol
            Code: Response (2)
            Id: 140
            Length: 7
            Type: Identity (1)
            Identity: uu
    AVP: l=18 t=Message-Authenticator(80): 6f65b6ecd4f665733fc5ca4edb296252
```

and here is my server respond

```
RADIUS Protocol
Code: Access-Challenge (11)
Packet identifier: 0x18 (24)
Length: 63
Authenticator: b16435719986e75542bee8e422ef690b
[This is a response to a request in frame 1]
[Time from request: 0.012348000 seconds]
Attribute Value Pairs
    AVP: l=25 t=EAP-Message(79) Last Segment[1]
        Type: 79
        Length: 25
        EAP fragment: 018c001704100245ca55b3e22343afe94ec324941d2841
        Extensible Authentication Protocol
            Code: Request (1)
            Id: 140
            Length: 23
            Type: MD5-Challenge EAP (EAP-MD5-CHALLENGE) (4)
                [Expert Info (Warning/Security): Vulnerable to MITM attacks. If possible, change EAP type.]
            EAP-MD5 Value-Size: 16
            EAP-MD5 Value: 0245ca55b3e22343afe94ec324941d28
            EAP-MD5 Extra Data: 41
    AVP: l=18 t=Message-Authenticator(80): b51a14486177ff84b584ac749acae88a
```

Answer (score 0):

had found out that the client devices(apple iphones) doesn't not follow the old rules, they didn't reply a nak saying that they dont support md5 method. iphones just ignore the reply and resend the access-request again...